# Algorithm that finds all the recurring substrings in a string

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, computational-mathematics, dynamic-programming, programming

I need to find all the recurring substrings in a string without considering the "overlapping" recurring substrings. For example if I have *ABCDABCDACCACCACCABDC*, here the recurring substrings are ABCD (2 times), ACC (3 times) and AB (3 times) etc... but without considering the cases like CCACC that would repeat two times if you take the common CC (the CC in bold *ABCDABCDACCA**CC**ACCABDC*). Is there an algorithm that can find these substrings and that has been implemented in some programming language like Python ?

In Google you can find many ways to obtain the "longest common substring". But I need all the recurring substrings, so not only the longest one but of all the lengths... (like the example that I wrote).

I suspect that it is not a trivial problem and my actual poor knowledges in programming do not help me in solving the problem. So I ask you if some matematician has invented it . Maybe there is an algorithm to find this that has a precise name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why ACC should be seen as recurring when A, B, C, D, ACCA, BC, CDA and many more aren't.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499968/finding-all-repeated-substrings-in-a-string-and-how-often-they-appear ?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path you are right I edit it

Comment: An obvious way is to just parse through the string with substrings of length $k$ letting $k$ vary between $1$ and len(yourString) by using a for or while loop... But maybe a mergesort algorithm keeping everything in alphabetical order (in each parsing) would be more efficient.

Comment: A question that might be of interest: do the occurrences have to be disjoint? For instance, does CCACCA count as recurring in your example?

Comment: yes all the recurring substrings sorry ! So also CCA .

Comment: I have edited the post by writing just "etc..." in order to say that I want all the recurring substrings @SaucyO'Path .

Comment: Let's put it like this: does the substring CCACC count as recurring in this example, seeing as it appears twice as a substring?

Comment: Good question @SaucyO'Path ... no I do not want those cases. I edited again the question. Thank you for the observations !

Comment: @AdamRubinson that's not obvious... at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm for this problem would be:

```
given a string s of length N
for i between 0 and N / 2
    for j between 2 and N / 2
        for k between j and N - i - j:
            if s[i : i+j] == s[i + k : i + j + k]
                count an occurence of this substring (s[i:i+j])
```

Where $s[x:y]$ is the substring from index $x$ to $y$.

$i$ is the start of the string, $j$ is the length of a substring, and $k$ is used to find reoccurences of the string (starting at $i+k$).

This has a runtime complexity of $O(n^3)$ where $n$ is the length of the string s. It can certainly be optimized by preprocessing the string and applying dynamic programming principles, but you haven't specified any requirements on performance.

However - Your question is likely better placed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: thank you @naslundx . Why /2 ?

Comment: @Manuela a substring cannot be longer than half the string, since then you couldn't fit two of them inside the string.

Comment: why does j start from 2  ?

Comment: @Manuela I've added clarifications for i, j, k.